# How to run many keys through a Python function

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary like this mydict = {}

```
{5200:{'C1': 0.2, 'C2': 0.8, 'C3': 0.3}, 
 5201: {'C1': 0.0, 'C2': 0.8, 'C3': 0.2},
 5202: {'C1': 0.0, 'C2': 0.8, 'C3': 0.2},
...}
```

I then create a function that gives me a result for every key I insert.

```
def myfunction()
```

To get my results I write

```
myfunction(mydict, 5200)
```

Is it possible to insert all my keys [5200, 5201, 5202,..] into that function so I can have a list of the results?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use *list comprehension* for this:

```
[ myfunction(mydict, key) for key in mydict ]
```

or you can use `map(..)`:

```
from functools import partial

list(map(partial(myfunction, mydict), mydict))
```

Note however that dictionaries are *unordered* (until [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)), and thus that the keys can be enumerated in every possible order. This is not due to the way we here iterate over it: when you store key-value pairs in a dictionary, then the order is "lost" in the dictionary.

Comment: Re: unordered dictionaries, they are *insertion* ordered in Python 3.6+, as an implementation detail in 3.6, can be relied upon in 3.7.

Comment: @jpp: yes, I know, although I personally would still not consider this very useful: passing a linked list through key-value pairs make the data structure theoretically larger. More modern languages make this feature more optionally available.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a **set** to store the outputs, since dictionary keys are not ordered:

```
{myfunction(mydict, k) for k in in mydict}
```

*note that using a set requires all the outputs of `myfunction` to be hashable*

Or, if you want to sort the keys so that the output is a list of the results of sorted keys (i.e. `5200`, `5201`, etc.):

```
[myfunction(mydict, k) for k in sorted(list(mydict.keys()))]
```

Comment: What if the `myfunc` produces results that are *unhashable*?

Comment: Re: dictionary keys not being ordered, they are *insertion* ordered in Python 3.6+, as an implementation detail in 3.6, can be relied upon in 3.7.